# Inject same instance based on context in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying inject the same instance into some of objects and another instance to another list of objects, based on some condition.

```
interface IChannelContext
{
    TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> Decoder { get; }
    IFilter Filter { get; }
}

interface IMsgSeqNumFilter
{
    bool CheckMsgSeqNumGreater(byte[] buffer);
}

class ChannelContext : IChannelContext
{
    public TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> Decoder { get; }
    public IMsgSeqNumFilter MsgSeqNumFilter { get; }

    public ChannelContext(TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> decoder, IMsgSeqNumFilter msgSeqNumFilter )
    {
        Decoder = decoder;
        MsgSeqNumFilter = msgSeqNumFilter;
    }
}

class MsgSeqNumFilter : IMsgSeqNumFilter
{
    int maxMsgSeqNum = -1;

    public bool CheckMsgSeqNumGreater(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I have to inject the same filter instance for the same decoder instances. And for different decoder instances there should be injected different instances.

How can I do this? Thanks.

**Update 1** Object graph according to Steven's comment. Without using container and interfaces.

```
class MsgSeqNumFilter
{
    int maxMsgSeqNum = -1;

    public bool CheckMsgSeqNumGreater(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class NetworkAddress
{
    public string IP { get; }
    public int Port { get; }

    public NetworkAddress(string ip, int port)
    {
        IP = ip;
        Port = port;
    }
}

class ChannelContext
{
    public NetworkAddress Address { get; }
    public TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> Decoder { get; }
    public MsgSeqNumFilter MsgSeqNumFilter { get; }

    public ChannelContext(NetworkAddress address, TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> decoder, MsgSeqNumFilter msgSeqNumFilter )
    {
        Address = address;
        Decoder = decoder;
        MsgSeqNumFilter = msgSeqNumFilter;
    }
}

class NetworkManager
{
    CancellationToken parentToken;

    public MulticastReceiveManager(IEnumerable<ChannelContext> channels, CancellationToken parentToken)
    {
        this.parentToken = parentToken;
        foreach (var channelContext in channels) AddChannel(channelContext);
    }

    public void AddChannel(ChannelContext channelContext)
    {
    }
}

class PacketDecoder
{
    public TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> DecoderA { get; } = new TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message>();
    public TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message> DecoderB { get; } = new TransformManyBlock<byte[], Message>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parentTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        NetworkAddress addrA1 = new NetworkAddress("1.1.1.1", 101);
        NetworkAddress addrA2 = new NetworkAddress("1.1.1.2", 102);
        MsgSeqNumFilter filterA = new MsgSeqNumFilter();
        NetworkAddress addrB1 = new NetworkAddress("2.2.2.1", 201);
        NetworkAddress addrB2 = new NetworkAddress("2.2.2.2", 202);
        MsgSeqNumFilter filterB = new MsgSeqNumFilter();

        var packetDecoder = new PacketDecoder();
        var channels = new List<ChannelContext>();
        channels.Add(new ChannelContext(addrA1, packetDecoder.DecoderA, filterA);
        channels.Add(new ChannelContext(addrA2, packetDecoder.DecoderA, filterA);
        channels.Add(new ChannelContext(addrB1, packetDecoder.DecoderB, filterB);
        channels.Add(new ChannelContext(addrB2, packetDecoder.DecoderB, filterB);

        var NetworkManager = new NetworkManager (channels, parentTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using Dependency Injection?

Comment: How do you create ChannelContext instances ?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Can you update your question and show an example of how your object graph should look like. or instance, you can do this by showing how you would `new` up the graph without a container (e.g. like the example in [this blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/)).

Comment: @Steven, I've updated according to your comment. Maybe I should change my classes structure?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why downvoted after update?

Comment: I think in your case is better of wiring this part of your application by hand. I would leave the code in your `Program.Main` as is and register only your `NetworkManager` in the container so it can be injected into other classes.

Comment: @Steven, thanks. Finally I did it this way already.

Answer (score -2):

Create `static` array of decoders and pass them to your `ChannelContext` instances. Consider using **Dependency Injection**.

Comment: your answer is very broad. Is it possible to be more specific, perhaps with code samples illustrating how this would work to solve the questioner's particular problem?